# Is there a way to detect if a polyline is/is-not within the boundaries of a road in here maps api?

Tags: javascript, gps, gis, here-api

I'm building an application that gets coordinates from a gps device. I would like to account for the case that the gps skips any points it has been to, which could result in polylines not following the roads correctly (e.g. if it skipped some turns or curves).. 
Hence, I would like to be able to check if my strip ever cuts across non roads

Answer (score 2):

You should parse your data using the [Route Match Extension](https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/route-match/topics/overview.html). This will return a route which snaps to the road network supported by HERE. It is then a trivial matter to compare your raw data geocoordinates with the parsed file which will only contain coordinate from the road network (when using `car` routemode) or roads and footpaths (when using `pedestrian` routemode)

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  -d @myfilename \
  'http://rme.cit.api.here.com/1/matchroute.json?routemode=car&app_id=<APP_ID>&app_code=<APP_CODE>'
```

Where `@myfilename` holds your GPS trace.